# SSIS package - loop through different connections for Execute SQL task

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am creating an MSSQL2008 SSIS package to generate and email reports from database tables. It works perfectly on a single database.  The client is running 3 different databases used by 3 different divisions.  The database structure is exactly the same. All three databases are located on the same server, same security / credentials are used.

I created a "For Each Loop Container" in my SSIS package that loops through the list of 3 items and populates it into a variable.  How do I now take that and pass it to the "Execute SQL Task" to run three times (once for each database)?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a lot easier than I expected.

I went to Properties of the "Execute SQL Task" and under "Expressions" for "Connection" I specified @varDBName, which was the variable I populated in the outer "for each" loop.  I also needed to set "DelayValidation" property to "True" so it's only evaluated during run-time.
I hope this helps somebody else.